# Sqlite3 Как проверить существование записи?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, sqlite3

Когда перезапускаешь бота с команды старт то бот вылетает библиотека бота(pyTelegramBotAPI)

```
import sqlite3
import telebot
from telebot import types


token='Токен'
bot=telebot.TeleBot(token)
conn = sqlite3.connect('db/Database.db', check_same_thread=False)
cursor = conn.cursor()




def db_table_val(User_id: int, User_name: str, User_surname: str, Username: str):
     cursor.execute('INSERT INTO Users (User_id, User_name, User_surname, Username) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)', (User_id, User_name, User_surname, Username))
     conn.commit()


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def button_message(message):
     us_id = message.from_user.id
     us_name = message.from_user.first_name
     us_sname = message.from_user.last_name
     username = message.from_user.username
     db_table_val(User_id=us_id, User_name=us_name, User_surname=us_sname, Username=username)
     bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Привет',reply_markup=markup)

bot.infinity_polling(none_stop=True)
```

Мне нужно:
сделать проверку на существование User_id в базе
Например:
Если получена команда /start то:

проверить существование данного пользователя в базе

если пользователя нет то:

Внести данные пользователя в базу данных

если пользователь существует в базе данных то:

Прислать ответ: вы уже есть в базе данных

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как насчёт через попытаться "достать" из бд юзера, и запихнуть ответ в переменную?

Например:
is_user = #обращаешься к бд, ищешь в ней юзера по айди

Если такой пользователь существует, в переменной будет некое значение. Если нет - False.
Затем просто выполнить проверку через if/else.

Например:
if is_user:
#отправляем сообщение "вы уже есть в бд"
else:
#добавляй данные в бд

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).